# Is PHP imagecopyresampled OS dependant?

Tags: php

My PHP code works OK on Windows and Ubuntu 12. But when I upload it to Ubuntu 16 then resized images have weird horizontal lines.

[Good image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SzSz.jpg)

[Bad image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i5Ug.jpg)

It's not PHP version, I tried them all from 5.6 to 7.2.

It's not php.ini, I tried to copy php.ini and restart Apache.

It's not Apache, I saved the image on server and downloaded it via FTP.

```
$big = imagecreatefromjpeg('big.jpg');
$small = imagecreatetruecolor(119, 180);
imagecopyresampled($small, $big, 0, 0, 0, 0, 119, 180, 785, 1181);
imagejpeg($small, 'small.jpg', 100);
```

Comment: Please add the code you are using, as well as the original dimensions and resized dimensions of the image. It's not really possible to diagnose the problem without a [mcve].

Comment: Code doesn't matter. I tried every code on Stack Overflow and the resized image is always different on Ubuntu 12 and 16.

Comment: This looks like a floating-point error. You’re resizing to a width that isn’t a divisor of the original, so you’re going to have strange rounding errors.

Comment: Is one machine 32-bit and the other(s) 64, or vice versa?

Comment: You are right , this is related to image size. I created a 1000x2000 image. Resized to 500x1000 it looks perfect. Resized to 500x1001 it has horizontal lines. Resized to 501x1000 it has vertical lines. I have checked my OS and PHP on all machines twice, they are all 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-wrote the code so that now it works everywhere without background noise. I extend the canvas so that division by thumbnail size results in integer. I can do that because the background is always white.

```
$extended_width = ceil($original_width / $thumbnail_width) * $thumbnail_width;
$extended_height = ceil($original_height / $thumbnail_height) * $thumbnail_height;
$extended_image = imagecreatetruecolor($extended_width, $extended_height);
$white = imagecolorallocate($extended_image, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($extended_image, 0, 0, $white);
imagecopy($extended_image, $original_image, ($extended_width - $original_width) / 2, ($extended_height - $original_height) / 2, 0, 0, $original_width, $original_height);
```